# Whether pre-installed app will receive ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a `“stopped”` state so they will not be able to run until the user explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this state.

Does this mean that even pre-installed app will not receive `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`?

Check [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html) for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [release notes of Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

`Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents.`

Additionally, System (pre-installed) apps will not be set to this `stopped` state, therefor they will already receive the intents.

Comment: Even I had the same thing in mind that system apps will not be set to stopped state.In this link the answer given by Mark confuses me https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/P2lGdvK2WEg

Comment: I also read that, but I guess he misunderstood the 'preinstalled' part.